# incoming and outgoing friend request in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to create friendship system in my laravel app so I need to load all users(incoming request, outgoing request and other new users)
For this my controller is like that

```
$users = User::with([
            'friendships' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('sender_id', Auth::id());
            }
        ])
        ->where('users.id', '!=', Auth::id())
        ->get();
```

My view

```
@foreach($records as $i=>$all_user)
    <tr>
      <td>{{++$i}}</td>
      <td>{{$all_user['name']}}</td>
      <td>{{$all_user['email']}}</td>
      @forelse($all_user['friendships'] as $req_status)
        <td><a href="{{ url('/send_req') }}/{{$all_user->id}}" class="btn btn-success">{{$req_status->status}}</a></td>   
      @empty
        <td><a href="{{ url('/send_req') }}/{{$all_user->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">send Req</a></td>
      @endforelse   
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

but this code have a lot of flaws.
I get all users except login one but there is no record of incoming requests. So if user have any incoming request so the status in my view should changed

my user model is like that

```
function friendships()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Friendship','recipient_id','id');
    }
```

table of friendship is

```
Schema::create(config('acquaintances.tables.friendships'), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->morphs('sender');
            $table->morphs('recipient');
            $table->string('status')->default('pending')->comment('pending/accepted/denied/blocked/');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: can you share your models or a schema of your db

Comment: check updated question

Comment: i dont get why you used moph , what is your polymorph model exactly ?

Comment: using this tutorial https://github.com/hootlex/laravel-friendships

Comment: it for laravel 5 , i am writing you an answer that will guide you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is package that can help you establish a friendship system in laravel with ease like [this one](https://github.com/multicaret/laravel-acquaintances)  i didnt use it personaly , i did a follow system in one of my portfolio projects [here](https://github.com/HijenHEK/twitterClone) and somewhat a request accept system too [here](https://github.com/HijenHEK/real-time-chat-laravel-vue)

what i suggest you try manually is somthing close to this .

#### friendable trait for User Model

```
public function sentRequests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friendships', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}

public function recievedRequests()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friendships', 'friend_id', 'user_id');
}

public function friends()
{
    $sentAccepted = $this->sentRequests()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get();
    $recievedAccepted = ->$this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted', true)->get();

    return $sentAccepted->merge($recievedAccepted); 

}

public sendRequest(User $user){
      $this->sendRequests()->create(['friend_id' , $user->id]);
}
public acceptRequest(User $user){
     $request_id = $this->recievedRequests()->where('friend_id' , $user->id)->first()->id;
     if($request_id) {
         return $this->recievedRequests()->updateExistingPivot($request_id , ['accepted' => true]) ;
     }
     return false ;
}
```

#### friendships table

```
Schema::create('friendships', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->foreignId('friend_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->boolean('accepted')->default(false);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to set [foreign keys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) in your migrations.

Comment: But how should i merge all of them as you can see my view file I want to load all users and their friendship status ?

Comment: for all users ? index for all friendship records ? i dont understand why would you do that , but i ll tweak the answer